# Maximum string length of windows workflow parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, string, workflow, workflow-foundation

In my sequential workflow, i am getting the string as a parameter from another workflow host. The actual size of the string is more than 512, but while i am recieving it from the workflow host i am getting the string with length of 512, beyond that is getting truncated.

Where may be the issue is? Do i need to change any configuration settings in the workflow? or need to add any attributes while defining the workflow parameter?

Thanx in advance

Comment: I have found the issue and it is related to the data model where the column length is set to 512. Anyhow, to my question, Ron Jacobs answer is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation to the size of string arguments.  I just did a quick test which verified that I can pass a 1K string to a Workflow.